# Rendering a chart with multiple y axes will display both datasets on the larger scale

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

Rendering a chart with multiple y axes will display both datasets on the larger scale. I'm trying multiple ways in the chart options to tell the second y axis to use another scale. Expected behavior is the second dataset to render on the second scale.

I've forked the vue-chartjs repo example to share

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xchppm?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your y-axis scale objects are `y: {...}` and `y1: {...}`, then `y` and `y1` are your y-axis IDs.

These IDs are added to the appropriate dataset options as `yAxisID`, (your code has a typo in `yAxisId` where the 'd' should be uppercase)

```js
  datasets: [
    {
      yAxisID: 'y',
      label: 'Data One',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: [6027, 5369, 5739, 6123, 6345, 6901, 5802],
    },
    {
      yAxisID: 'y1',
      label: 'Data Two',
      data: [0.004, 0.006, 0.002, 0.008, 0.001, 0.003, 0.005],
    },
  ],
```

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xchppm-boiduh?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts)

Comment: ah! i swore i tried that variation but i just realized i was using 'yAxisId' instead of 'yAxisID'  thanks for catching that